# Show a user their recently viewed posts

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am working on a project that showcases a number of products, so I'd like to add a "recently viewed product" selection that keeps track of the last 5 or so viewed products or posts.

I saw [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recently-viewed-posts/) but its 2 years old and as of now doesn't look to be supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close) here. Instead, try http://wordpress.org/support

Comment: You could write your own php function to ride along in your site's header and pass along session/cookie data to each page. Then intercept that on sidebar or wherever, so it could interpret that (just capture the post IDs) as your recently viewed items.

Comment: i dont this its a plugin question @bungeshea - he just said he looked for a ready solution but found an old one. Also i find this an intresting question ;) (in my point of view)... johnathon... are you talking about looged in users or visitors? ... GhostToast i would love to see an basic example for your solution.

Comment: @SagiveSEO The question had the [tag:plugin-recommendation] tag

Comment: Indeed it did have the plugin recommendation tag, was a noob mistake. Was more looking towards plugin advice the tag fit considering the situation. 

I surprisingly got the old plugin working and set up to handle custom posts, and as of now its working. Its been a week or so, but i believe the old plugin worked - which is great and saved me tons of time. 

For the record this was set up for all users, and will be used to show previously viewed products - a nice easy way to compare multiple products.

Comment: I updated an answer, you might find it useful. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63272/19683

Answer (score 6):

You can add a timestamp to your post meta each time a product is viewed, then query the five most recently viewed products.

Assuming you are using a custom post type named 'product', add the following inside the loop of your single-product.php template file:

```
<?php 
if (get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'product' )
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_last_viewed', current_time('mysql') );
?>
```

To display the five most recently viewed products:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_key' => '_last_viewed',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
query_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: This would show the same products to everybody.